# Meteor Handlebars templates: switching from text to input

Tags: forms, meteor, handlebars.js, edit-in-place

One part of my meteor application is a semi-collaborative table where users can edit different rows at the same time. When a user is editing a row, the static text values need to switch to input boxes so that the values can be edited and then saved. I would like a template/helper to do this, essentially I want:

```
<td>
{{#if iAmEditing}}
   {{foo}}
{{else}}
   <input type="text" name="foo" value="{{foo}}">
</td>
```

except that there are several columns with different values of "foo" and I don't want to copy and paste this several times. What's the right way to approach this with templates and helpers?

Another approach might be to use the HTML5 `contenteditable` attribute. Either way, what is the right way to template these values with handlebars?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to integrate with [Bootstrap Editable](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/)

Comment: Good reference, I'll check it out.

Comment: @AndrewMao I am looking for something similar, let me know if you want work on a Meteor Package, where users can collaborately work on a edit in place document.

Comment: I don't think you need to do that for a document, there is already [ot.js](https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js/) for that, and you would not want to write that from scratch.

Comment: First, I have found https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-x-editable-bootstrap, which I am using for a collaboratively editable spreadsheet. Second, I am working on https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs. Check it out at http://documents.meteor.com :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, an answer to the original question...

As of today, handlebars partials can't accept anything other than a context argument, but helpers can. Hence. you can define a helper that sets up the context for the template:

Coffeescript:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "eventCell", (context, field, editable) ->
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(
    Template._eventCell
      _id: context._id
      field: field
      value: context[field]
      editable: editable
  )
```

Template:

```
<template name="_eventCell">
    <td><div data-ref="{{field}}" class="{{#if editable}}editable{{/if}}">
        {{value}}
    </div></td>
</template>
```

Then, I  just use the following to render each field:

```
{{eventCell this "province" iAmEditing}}
```

I ended up integrating with bootstrap editable, so the template is a little different than my original question. Also, I'm not sure if this is *the* best way to do it, but it's a lot cleaner than what I had before.

Answer (score 0):

[meteor-editable](https://atmospherejs.com/package/meteor-editable) is a new project implementing something like x-editable, but nicely integrated with Meteor reactivity. Unfortunately inline editing is not supported yet (you have to use a popover the way it's set up now).